# Getting a "RuntimeError: Expected bias tensor to be a vector" while trying to do full integer quantization on a keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

Keras version - 2.4.3
TF version - 2.3.0

The code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import numpy as np

tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution(
    config=None, device_policy=None, execution_mode=None
)

def representative_dataset_gen():
    i = 0
    for i in range(1000, 3190):
        img_crop = cv2.imread(<SOME_PATH> + str(i) + '.jpg')
        img_crop = img_crop.astype(np.float32)
        img_cropped = cv2.resize(img_crop, (150, 150))
        print (img_cropped.shape)
        oImage = np.reshape(img_cropped, (1, 150, 150, 3))
        yield [oImage]

def main(args):
    """ Main entry point """

    # Build the model (just the graph)
    keras_model = build_dlib_model(use_bn=False)
    keras_model.summary()

    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(keras_model)
    converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
    converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset_gen
    converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
    converter.experimental_new_converter = True
    converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
    converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8
    tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()
    open('./tflite_quant/dlib_tf_full_int_quant.tflite', "wb").write(tflite_quant_model)
```

Executing this gives the following error

```
File "main.py", line 74, in <module>
    main(parse_arg(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "main.py", line 43, in main
    tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()
  File "/home/anand/virtual_environs/env_16.04_py3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 831, in convert
    self).convert(graph_def, input_tensors, output_tensors)
  File "/home/anand/virtual_environs/env_16.04_py3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 638, in convert
    result = self._calibrate_quantize_model(result, **flags)
  File "/home/anand/virtual_environs/env_16.04_py3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 452, in _calibrate_quantize_model
    inference_output_type, allow_float, activations_type)
  File "/home/anand/virtual_environs/env_16.04_py3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/optimize/calibrator.py", line 98, in calibrate_and_quantize
    np.dtype(activations_type.as_numpy_dtype()).num)
RuntimeError: Expected bias tensor to be a vector.
```

I am trying to convert a constructed keras h5 model (with random initialized weights) to tflite with full integer quantization. I am able to convert it to tflite and do dynamic range quantization. However full integer quantization (even with float fallback) is giving me the above RuntimeError